# power supply by using stepdown transformer

Tags: power-supply, power

i was trying to make 5V, 1Apower supply  using stepdown transformer, some doides and capacitors and finally 7805 regulator. however when i tried to drive servo motor from it i was not getting stable output for small capacitor values at the output of 7805. the output got stable when i used about 700 uF electrolytic capacitor. the datasheet however says 10uf is sufficient.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Do you have a schematic?

Comment: Specs for the transformer?

Comment: What do you mean by "not stable"? Are you seeing oscillation or just dips in the supply?  Scope shots? What's the load profile? What is the peak current draw of the servo motor?  Can you use a current probe to see what the load current is doing?

Comment: If your goal is to learn how to design a good power supply, you'll need to at least provide the full schematic.  If your goal is to power your servo, buy a small inexpensive efficient modern switcher.

Comment: i bet your inductive motor is all kinds of noisy, and that affects the 7805 stability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimum input voltage for a 7805 voltage regulator is 7V. If the input drops below 7V then the regulator will not regulate and the output voltage will drop. The large capacitor should be at the input of the 7805 so that the input never drops below 7V.

700uF is not enough capacitance if the rectifier is full-wave since a 1A load will cause its filtering to be poor. Use 1000uF or more.

Answer (score -1):

the problem was i was using only electrolytic capacitors. when i used ceramic capacitor at the input and output servo motor worked like a charm. no more ripples. thanks for all the answers